# Duplicates removal in Python's dataframe + timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

a total newbie here. Will try explaining it as clear as possible :)

So, I have received this log .csv file of the decisions about the articles, please see below.

```
created_at                  user_id user_email          article_id  key      value
2023-12-05T20:04:45.088Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           1      included   -1
2023-12-05T20:05:32.964Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           2      included   -1
2023-12-05T20:06:31.980Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           3      included   -1
2023-12-05T20:06:33.730Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           3      included   -1
2023-12-05T20:06:36.387Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           3      included    1
2023-12-05T20:06:38.621Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           3      included    1
2023-12-05T20:06:56.200Z    111111  abc@gmail.com           3      included   -1
```

Please see the entries for the article_id #3. I need to remove all the entries before the last one. I have tried applying the following

```
data_last = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['article_id'], keep='last'
```

but there was no luck (the code just left me random rows starting off around like 28-29). This needs to be done across the whole file (which is 17349 rows).

Thank you everyone in advance!

EDIT: The result of the code I have applied (the one mentioned above as well as in the solutions) looks like this. Please note that the initial user info changed as the code just removed the info all the way till the row 29. Also, the number of rows has decreased to 8035 from 17349. It would have made sense but the number of articles was > 7000 and the entries of two users would have been around double that (after the duplicates are excluded).

```
29  2023-12-16T14:17:52.687Z    222222  dce@gmail.com   1   included    -1
31  2023-12-16T14:22:13.629Z    222222  dce@gmail.com   2   included    -1
289 2023-12-16T15:53:46.552Z    222222  dce@gmail.com   3   included    -1
290 2023-12-16T15:53:49.146Z    222222  dce@gmail.com   4   included    -1
291 2023-12-16T15:53:54.974Z    222222  dce@gmail.com   5   included    -1
```

Comment: "the code just left me random rows starting off around like 28-29". What do you mean? Better show the result of `drop_duplicates` properly formatted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the last row in order of creation, sort by `created_at` and then call `drop_duplicates` keeping the last row:

```py
# Sort by date and keep the last value
df = df.sort_values("created_at")
df = df.drop_duplicates("article_id", keep="last")
# Convert dates to format YYYY-MM-DD
df["created_at"] = df["created_at"].dt.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")
```

Result:

```
   created_at  user_id     user_email  article_id       key  value
0  2023-04-05   111111  abc@gmail.com           1  included     -1
1  2023-05-05   111111  abc@gmail.com           2  included     -1
6  2023-06-05   111111  abc@gmail.com           3  included     -1
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help solved the date question. However, the duplicates are still there, unfortunately. I have updated the initial question description

Comment: I don't understand your question then. What duplicates are you referring to? There's only one row for each `article_id`. Maybe post the expected outcome of your example.

Comment: If you only want to keep the last row regardless of `article_id`, you have to drop duplicates in relation to some other column, like: `df = df.drop_duplicates("key", keep="last")`. This will keep only one row for each different value in column `key`.

Comment: ok, let me paraphrase my initial question. So, there is user "x" and user "y", which both were making decisions about the article_id's. What I want to do is to remove all the duplicates of both users' decisions about each article leaving just the last decision made about each listed article.

Comment: If I understand it, you want to keep the latest row that each `user_id` chose for each `article_id`. If that's the case, you should drop the duplicates based on these two columns: `df = df.drop_duplicates(["user_id", "article_id"], keep="last")`. If that's not it, maybe you could update your question to include more users in the example and the expected result.

Comment: you the man, thanks a bunch buddy, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was about to split the table in two and try sorting stuff out there but you helped me :)